# Animate text to change color from top to bottom

Tags: html, css

I have some text that I want to animate. The text should change color from white to green from top to bottom. I want the new color to basically drop from the top.

```css
body{
background-color: lightblue;
}
#test {
  animation: changeColor infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  font-size: 40px;
  color:white;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    color: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #2E7D32 50%) bottom;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">The</div>
```

---

**An Example**

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/4-ways-to-animate-the-color-of-a-text-link-on-hover/) for the below snippet. The following animation occurs on hover, however this is just an example to demonstrate what I wish to achieve. Some changes I require are that the font colour should change from top to bottom and it should use `keyframes`(animation).

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow:800&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Barlow", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: royalblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, midnightblue, midnightblue 50%, royalblue 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  transition: background-position 275ms ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link Hover</a>
```

Comment: linear gradients cannot be used as `color`.

Comment: https://cssgradient.io/blog/css-gradient-text/

Comment: @Paulie_D I see, I saw a similar approach used for changing background colour, I was trying to use it for color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to accomplish, so I'm answering my own question.

```js
let titleIDThe = document.getElementById("titleIDThe");
titleIDThe.classList.add("animateColor");
```

```css
.animateColor {
  animation: changeColor infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, #2E7D32 50%);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  20% {
    background-position: 0% -100%;
  }
  30% {
    background-position: 0% -100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="titleIDThe">The</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`background` + `background-clip` might be what you look for:

because of a demo (below) it could not be just a comment :) .

*reset the gradient to your needs if you need a sharp color transition*

```css
body{
background:lightblue;
}
#test {
  animation: changeColor infinite  linear  5s forwards;
  font-size: 40px;
  color:transparent;
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #2E7D32 , white, #2E7D32 ) bottom left/ 100% 600% ;
background-clip:text;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
   
 to  {  background-position: top left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">The</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I was using linear gradient incorrectly. I actually want the color to drop like that of the text(not the background)

Comment: @rishi did you run the snippet *(gradient is the text not background which remains lightblue)* ? have you tried to reset the stop/start colors ? do you have an exemple of the expected result ?

Comment: I want the font color of the text to change (not the background color of the text). I'll have to look around for the expected output, I don't have an example right now. Although I hope I was able to explain it.

Comment: I have added an example of something similar to what I wish to achieve